# How can I repair a Windows 7 bootloader without a Windows 7 disk?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, toshiba-laptop

My boss's laptop is unable to boot. He told me it had hard crashed so he removed the battery. After inserting the battery again and turning on the machine it gets past POST ("The Toshiba Screen") but I just get a flashing white prompt then it disappears and sits there.

I don't have the original CDs. What can I do? I do have a Ubuntu CD and a few other Linux CDs like Gparted and Clonezilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not even getting beyond the BIOS Post processes.  I would first pull up the BIOS and see if the hard drive is recognized. If not then that is probably your culprit and not Windows.

If you need to test your drive, I suggest using [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) which has a ton of hard disk testing tools.

Comment: Yeah the BIOS is passing post, I am able to get into the BIOS setup and stuff. Also it boots from my Windows 7 64-bit disc I just found around. The problem is that did not fix the boot problem.

Comment: This only reconfirms my thinking that this isn't a windows issue but rather a hard drive failure.

Comment: @ Solignis, Post your model of Dell and I can point you to a Dell hardware diagnostics CD

Comment: No no, The machine is question is a Toshiba, I was just saying how my Dell has the integrated restore option

Comment: Hmmm how can I test for a dead disk? See if I can read data from it with Ubuntu Live?

Comment: You know I just thought about it, the Windows 7 Disc saw the "C:" drive when I had it look for installations to repair, So I am kinda confused what is going on.

Comment: Yes, see if you can read data from your disk in Linux.

Comment: yeah it loads ubuntu and i can mount the disk and also read a few text files from it, so everything seems to be good there.

Comment: Wow this post is old, I forgot it about this one. It turned out to be a dead drive. I pulled it out and it a really really hot like the bearing had seized.

Answer (score 2):

Some PCs have a Windows recovery environment partition on the hard drive, you would use F8 at the bios splash screen to access the Advanced Boot Options screen, then select repair your  computer.

.

[image]

Comment: That was the first thing I was thinking, cuz my dell has that option. I cannot even get to F8. I just does nothing

Comment: @Solignis it's not you dell it's the windows boot loader.  All Windows installs have this option no matter the computer model.

Comment: really? I thought that was more of a new thing that not all manufactures did.

Answer (score -1):

Try loading from some live Linux cd/flashstick. If it's ok, I think you can try using [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: ms-sys? what is that?

Comment: It's a program that writes MBR of a selected Windows version to the disk. If you have yours damaged, it may help. Just make sure it's the correct version, for Windows 7 you may need to download the latest version of the program.

Comment: I will look into it